# Kinetic energy and work-energy theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I don't understand how this step has done which i have marked so please help me

[[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnEn.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnEn.jpg)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnEn.jpgenter image description here]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! In future please use Math Jax to format the equations in your question. For a tutorial see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/945353

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lack of rigour in usual derivation of Work-Energy Theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177207/lack-of-rigour-in-usual-derivation-of-work-energy-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

By the product rule for differentiation $$\frac{d}{dt}(v\cdot v) = v\cdot\frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{dv}{dt}\cdot v  = 2v \cdot\frac{dv}{dt}$$

so the circled part equals the one approximately above it.